# Error creating connection to DB in Reactive Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, docker, cassandra, reactive-programming, reactive

I am trying to establish connection with Cassandra to read data using the reactive dependency of cassandra, and I am getting the following error. What can be the reason for this?

Dependency

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:2.2.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-core'
```

Logs

```
{
  "@version":1,
  "source_host":"192.168.1.3",
  "message":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: \
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean \
    with name 'reactiveSession' defined in class path resource \
    [com/company/pai/gm/ws/core/config/CassandraConfig.class]: \
    Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: \
    Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.cassandra.TraceReactiveSession] \
    from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@67424e82]", \
    "thread_name":"main", \
    "@timestamp":"2023-04-13T19:26:26.637+05:30", \
    "level":"WARN", \
    "logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext"
}
```

I have tried changing the versions of the dependency, but so far no luck.

Edit1 : I was using this dependency in build.gradle, commenting this out was able to establish connection. But I want to use both the dependecies together.

```
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that you can't connect to Cassandra from a Spring Boot app but the dependency you posted is for Spring Data.

In any case, a friendly reminder that you need to provide sufficient details when posting a question. The general guidance is that you:

1. provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace;
2. describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and
3. minimal sample code that replicates the problem.

You will need to update your original question with these details so we can help you.

In the meantime if you're interested, the [DataStax-Examples/spring-petclinic-reactive](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/spring-petclinic-reactive) project is a Reactive version of the Spring PetClinic application that has the full working sample code you could use as reference. Cheers!

Comment: I had followed a tutorial in which the dependencies were used as given in question : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-reactive. Also, I have seen further, that this is a dependency conflict issue